# error on running my javafxml application with Derby database

Tags: javafx, fxml, derby

I'm new in Java. I am writing a JavaFXML application in Netbeans IDE 8.2 that includes a class for connecting to a Derby database (DatabaseHandler.java) that first create a database for me.  But when i run the program, this database is not created in my project. Does any code is required to added or modified? Here is my codes. Please help me.

my program has 2 packages: -library.assistant.database -library.assistant.ui.addbook

### Codes for FXMLDocumentCntroller.java

```
package library.assistant.ui.addbook;
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton;
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextField;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import library.assistant.database.DatabaseHandler;

/**
 * FXML Controller class
 *
 * @author pc
 */
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

@FXML
private JFXTextField title;
@FXML
private JFXTextField id;
@FXML
private JFXTextField author;
@FXML
private JFXTextField publisher;
@FXML
private JFXButton saveButton;
@FXML
private JFXButton cancelButton;

DatabaseHandler databaseHandler;

/**
 * Initializes the controller class.
 */
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    databaseHandler = new DatabaseHandler();
}

@FXML
private void addBook(ActionEvent event) {
}

@FXML
private void cancel(ActionEvent event) {
}
```

}

---

Codes for DatabaseHandler.java

---

```
package library.assistant.database;
private static DatabaseHandler handler;

private static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:derby:database;create=true";
private static Connection conn = null;
private static Statement stmt = null;

public DatabaseHandler() {

    createConnection();
    setupBookTable();
}

void createConnection() {

    try {

        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver").newInstance();
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

void setupBookTable() {

    String Table_Name = "Book";
    try {

        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        DatabaseMetaData dbm = conn.getMetaData();
        ResultSet tables = dbm.getTables(null, null, Table_Name.toUpperCase(), null);
        if (tables.next()) {
            System.out.println("table" + Table_Name + "already exists. Ready for go!");

        } else {

            stmt.execute("CREATE TABLE " + Table_Name + "("
                    + "    id varchar(200) primary key,\n"
                    + "    title varchar(200),\n"
                    + "    author varchar(200),\n"
                    + "    publisher varchar(100),\n"
                    + "    isAvailable boolaen default true"
                    + " )");
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage() + " ... setupDatabase");
    } finally {

    }

}
```

### }

Codes for LibraryAssistant.java

---

```
package library.assistant.ui.addbook;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author pc
 */
public class LibraryAssistant extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

---

### Here is my fxml file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

 <?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton?>
 <?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextField?>
 <?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
 <?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
 <?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
 <?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="255.0" prefWidth="368.0" 
xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" 
fx:controller="library.assistant.ui.addbook.FXMLDocumentController">
<children>
  <VBox prefHeight="363.0" prefWidth="368.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" 
  AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" 
   AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
       <children>
      <JFXTextField fx:id="title" labelFloat="true" promptText="Book Title">
           <VBox.margin>
              <Insets left="10.0" right="10.0" top="20.0" />
           </VBox.margin>
        </JFXTextField>
        <JFXTextField fx:id="id" labelFloat="true" layoutX="20.0" 
     layoutY="30.0" promptText="Book ID">
           <VBox.margin>
              <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="20.0" />
           </VBox.margin>
        </JFXTextField>
        <JFXTextField fx:id="author" labelFloat="true" layoutX="20.0" 
   layoutY="30.0" promptText="Book Author">
           <VBox.margin>
              <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
           </VBox.margin>
        </JFXTextField>
        <JFXTextField fx:id="publisher" labelFloat="true" layoutX="10.0" 
    layoutY="55.0" promptText="Publisher">
           <VBox.margin>
              <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
           </VBox.margin>
        </JFXTextField>
        <HBox prefHeight="58.0" prefWidth="368.0">
           <children>
              <JFXButton fx:id="saveButton" onAction="#addBook" 
   prefHeight="58.0" prefWidth="200.0" stylesheets="@addbook.css" text="Save" 
  />
              <JFXButton fx:id="cancelButton" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="10.0" 
onAction="#cancel" prefHeight="58.0" prefWidth="200.0" 
stylesheets="@addbook.css" text="Cancel" />
           </children>
        </HBox>
     </children>
  </VBox>
  </children>
  </AnchorPane>
```

---

Comment: From the question thus posed, it is not clear what the problem is. Is the database not creating or getting any error? You will need more information to get help.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. The problem is that database is not created.

Comment: Do you get that `"table" + Table_Name + "already exists. Ready for go!"` In the console? And overall, are you sure the controller is initializing (it may not be specified in the `fxml` file for example)

Comment: The controller introduced in the fxml file.

Comment: The application problem was fixed and the database was created. But the following message appears in the console:  TYPE 'BOOLAEN' does not exist. ... setupDatabase

Comment: The problem was the word "boolean". At first i was teped: "boolaen". Now my problem is completely fixed.   ------->isAvailable boolaen default true